# How to handle Google Play Services not being installed - from a service

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm trying to use Google Play Services to retrieve location periodically. I need this in multiple activities so I extracted the part out as a service which listens for location updates and regularly broadcasts it back to my activities.

But how should I handle the issue when Google Play Services aren't available?

Google's example has them creating error dialogs, but they all need a current activity:
http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Instead my `onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult)` is received by the service and has no such current activity. My activities could check `GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this)` but they won't know `connectionResult.getErrorCode()` as they have no `connectionResult` so won't know what dialog to create.

Am I over-complicating things and there is some easier solution here?

Comment: If it fails you could send a broadcast back to your activity to launch the notification dialog. Prob not the best solution, but it is one.

Comment: You want to get your current location using GPS?

Comment: zgc7009, yes, that's my fallback plan. I should have mentioned.

Comment: berserk, I want to get it regularly. Not just once, but receive it as the user moves.

Comment: You can use this service: http://pastie.org/9300205

Comment: berserk, thanks, I will review the code, it looks useful. But I think it doesn't really answer the question asked as I think I need other Google Play Services features for the application as well.

Comment: @JohnM can u pls share how u have resolved ur issue i also stuck at same issue